# Nginx: How to forward requests to a port using proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, server, proxypass

I'm just getting started with Nginx and am trying to set up a server block to forward all requests on the subdomain `api.mydomain.com` to port 8080.

Here's what I've got:

**UPDATED:**

```
server {
  server_name api.mydomain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
  }
}

server {
  server_name www.mydomain.com;
  return 301 $scheme://mydomain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  server_name mydomain.com;

  root /var/www/mydomain.com;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

The server block exists in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and I have created a symlink in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

#### What I expect:

I'm running [deployd](http://deployd.com/) on port 8080. When I go to `api.mydomain.com/users` I expect to get a JSON response from the deployd API, but I get no response instead.

Also, my 301 redirect for `www.mydomain.com` is not working. That block was code I copied from [Nginx Pitfalls](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Server_Name).

#### What I've tried:

- Confirmed that `mydomain.com:8080/users` and `$ curl
  http://127.0.0.1:8080/users` return the expected response.
- Restarted the nginx service after making changes to the server block.
- Tried removing the `proxy_set_header` lines.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my problem was not with Nginx configuration but rather with my DNS settings. I had to create an `A NAME` record for each of my sub-domains (`www` and `api`). Rookie mistake.

A colleague of mine actually helped me troubleshoot the issue. We discovered the problem when using `telnet` from my local machine to connect to the server via IP address and saw that Nginx was, in fact, doing what I intended.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to explicitly capture the URL for your use case. The following should work for your location block:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Comment: I thought that too, but it didn't work...which is why I went the regex route. There must be something else going on in the config. My other server block, which just serves up static pages, is working fine.